# SQL difficulty with HAVING and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a table like this:

```
T_EARNED_DEGREES
================
STUDENT_ID   TERM_ID   DEGREE
      1000       400       BS
      1001       400       BS
      1002       400       BS
      1002       400       BS
      1003       500       BS
      1003       500       MS
      1000       600       MS
```

How would I write a query that selects all columns and rows for students who earned two (or more) degrees in the same term?

I imagine I need to use the `COUNT` or `HAVING` operators, and probably `GROUP BY`, but beyond that I'm lost.  I tried something very basic:

```
SELECT    STUDENT_ID,
          TERM_ID
FROM      T_EARNED_DEGREES
GROUP BY  STUDENT_ID,
          TERM_ID
HAVING    COUNT(DEGREE) > 1
```

And this (sort of) works, giving these results:

```
STUDENT_ID   TERM_ID
      1002       400
      1003       500
```

Student 1000 is excluded because degrees were earned in separate terms, and student 1001 is excluded because only one degree overall was earned.

However, I was hoping for these results, because I want to see all rows and columns:

```
STUDENT_ID   TERM_ID   DEGREE
      1002       400       BS
      1002       400       BS
      1003       500       BS
      1003       500       MS
```

But when I add the DEGREE column to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statements, only one result is returned:

```
STUDENT_ID   TERM_ID   DEGREE
      1002       400       BS
```

I imagine this is because student 1003's degrees were different (BS and MS), and so aren't grouped together.

How can I get what I want?  Again, I want to select all rows and column values, not just student and term.  (And of course my real schema is much more extensive; this is a highly simplified example.)

Comment: Does you T_EARNED_DEGREES table have a primary key that is not student id?

Comment: Looking at some of the answers, should "for students who earned two (or more) degrees in the same term" mean "for students who earned two (or more) DISTINCT degrees in the same term"?

Comment: @PatrickMarchand no, if a student earned two or more degrees in the same term I want them all.

Comment: So, just for one final clarification... the rows with student_id 1002 and term_id 400 should not be included because there is only one degree, right? What I'm getting at is whether the answers below should to be doing a COUNT(DISTINCT degree) or not.

Comment: @PatrickMarchand no, I don't want DISTINCT.  The rows with student_id 1002 and term_id 400 should be included.  (In my real schema, there are other columns that would indicate one of the BS degrees was in Chemistry and the other was in Biology, and I want to capture that information.)

Comment: @DerekHackett No, I don't think there is a separate PK field (It's actually a view instead of a table.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from t_earned_degrees 
where student_id in ( 
SELECT    STUDENT_ID
FROM      T_EARNED_DEGREES
GROUP BY  STUDENT_ID,
          TERM_ID
HAVING    COUNT(DEGREE) > 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use windowed `COUNT`

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID, TERM_ID) AS rn
  FROM T_EARNED_DEGREES
)
SELECT STUDENT_ID,TERM_ID,DEGREE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/KVES56193)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ STUDENT_ID ║ TERM_ID ║ DEGREE ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║       1002 ║     400 ║ BS     ║
║       1002 ║     400 ║ BS     ║
║       1003 ║     500 ║ BS     ║
║       1003 ║     500 ║ MS     ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

---

Without cte is even shorter:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID,TERM_ID,DEGREE
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID, TERM_ID) AS rn 
      FROM T_EARNED_DEGREES)
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `PARTITION` statement.  Thanks!